# Enquiry on uncountability of a set

Tags: real-analysis

Currently I am studying a theorem that says

Let $B$ be a nonempty set. Then following are equivalent

(i) $B$ be a countable set.

(ii)There is an injective mapping between $B$ and $Z+$.

Now we can easily prove that  (i) implies (ii). But is the converse true?? I mean any finite set has an injective mapping into $Z+$. I think I am understanding something wrong.  Any help would be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Countable" allows for the possibility that the set is finite. If your convention excludes this case, the theorem is false (to make it true, in case ii you would need to assume in addition that $B $ is infinite).

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks

Comment: In (ii), you probably mean "injective" rather than "infective".

Comment: By "injective mapping between $B$ and $Z+$" you probably mean "injective mapping from $B$ to $Z+$"? An injective map in the other direction would not imply countability of $B.$

Comment: @badjohn I love when people talk about monotonous functions.

Answer (score 0):

Notation. For any function $h$ and any $A\subset$ dom$(h)$ let $\{h(a):a\in A\}=h''A .$ ( Read: $h$ double-prime $A$.)

Let $f:B\to \mathbb Z^+$ be injective.  For $b\in B$ let $$g(b)=\{n\in \mathbb Z^+: f(b)\geq n\in f''B\}.$$ And let $N(b)$ be  be the number of members of $g(b).$

Then  $N:B\to \mathbb Z^+$ is injective. For if  $b,b'\in B$ with $b\ne b'$ and  $f(b)<f(b')$, then  $g(b)$ and $g(b')$ are finite subsets of $\mathbb Z^+$ with $g(b) \subsetneqq g(b').$ So $g(b)$ has fewer members than $g(b').$ So $N(b))<N(b').$

Suppose $N''B$ is not empty and has no largest member. Then $N''B=\mathbb Z^+.$ That is, $N:B\to \mathbb Z^+$ is a bijection: As follows:

(a). If $f(x)=\min f''B$ then $N(x)=1$. So $1\in N''B.$

(b). If  $N(x)=n,$ let $y=\min \{z\in f''B: z>f(x)\}.$ Since $y\in f''B$ there exists $x'\in B$ with $f(x')=y.$ Now by the def'n of $y$ we have $$g(x')=\{f(x')\}\cup g(x)$$ with $f(x')$ being greater than every member of $g(x).$ So $N(x')=1+N(x)=n+1.$

(c). So by induction on $n\in \mathbb Z^+$ we have $f''B\supset \mathbb Z^+.$